# Do characters get opposed attack rolls if they are "nauseated"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I was considering ways to effectively disarm, sunder, and trip enemies without huge investments of feats and magic items. I'm for instance carrying around an Adamantium LongSword (Merthuvial) making sundering more feasible for me. Unfortunately sundering isn't something you typically want to do because it destroys loot but I can imagine a scenario where it would be beneficial and said scenario occurs rather often. Large creatures with large weapons. No one in our group is large and that stuff is hard to carry around and in said enemies' hands is extremely dangerous.

Our resident arcane caster likes using disabling spells and is particularly fond of using spells that reduce enemy saves before hitting them with AoE spells like Web and Stinking Cloud.

All this to say if an enemy is currently "Nauseated" would they be able to perform an opposed attack roll or make an attack of opportunity? According to the text of the in SRD the answer would appear to be no but it seems very cheesy because it would mean guaranteed trips, sunders, and disarms.

http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Nauseated

> **Nauseated**
>
> Experiencing stomach distress. Nauseated creatures are unable to attack, cast spells, concentrate on spells, or do anything else requiring attention. The only action such a character can take is a single move action per turn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creatures that are nauseated can still participate in opposed rolls, including attack rolls.  You can think of this as their skill at holding on to their weapon, which does not require attention.

Creatures that are nauseated cannot make attacks of opportunity.

This is not particularly exploitable, because most effects that cause 'nauseated' offer Fortitude saves to resist.  Large creatures tend to have very good Fortitude saves.